# How to update angular child scope by an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm getting an array of data from server and going to update the `$scope` in angularJS.

The initial value is :

```
$scope.form = {};
```

I want to update dynamically like this:

```
$scope.form = {"firstname" : "Alex"};
```

both `firstname` and `alex` must update by an array like this:

```
sent.then(function(result) {
  angular.forEach(result.data.test, function(value, key){
    // ** something like this, but it doesn't work :
    var form_child = "{" + value.FieldName + ":" + value.FieldValue "}";
    $scope.form = form_child;
  });
});
```

How should I do line ** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array syntax :

```
$scope.form[value.FieldName] = value.FieldValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

in angular you don't have access to child scope, you only have access to parent's scopes.